# 12.04 disabling keyboard and mouse

Tags: keyboard

I'm actually new to Ubuntu and I've just installed a fresh copy of 12.04, I'm a convert from Windows because I'm just tired with all the backdoor activities.

You could say I'm a new convert, but I'm getting frustrated with this freezing of keyboard and mouse, I have no idea what is causing this action, unfortunately I am not in a position yet to provide accurate description of what is going on, I am hoping an expert can help me out with this issue.

I have tried rebooting but the problem is becoming persistent each time I reboot, a little advice will help me greatly.

NB
While typing this the desktop has just gone to sleep I can't reboot as both keyboard and mouse are not responding.

Comment: What hardware are you using?

Comment: I'm using logitech keyboard and mouseK500

Comment: What about your computer?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I simply swapped the mouse and keyboard around on the USB ports. Doesn't make sense but it worked. Also if its wireless keyboard or mouse. Unplug and re-plug while connected.

Also try different mouse and keyboard which I guess you don't have as you would have tried that already. I have many mice and keyboards lying around the house ;)